# How Do I Make this For Loop continue after the Thread finishes?

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, java.util.scanner, thread-sleep

Thread used

```
public class MissedThread extends Thread
{
    public synchronized void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Too slow");
        }catch(InterruptedException e){return;}
    }
}
```

Program that uses aforementioned Thread

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FastMath
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("How many questions can you solve?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total = in.nextInt();
        MissedThread m = new MissedThread();
        int right = 0;
        int wrong = 0;
        int missed = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<total;i++)
        {
            int n1 = (int)(Math.random()*12)+1;
            int n2 = (int)(Math.random()*12)+1;
            System.out.print(n1+" * "+n2+" = ");
            m.start();
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            if(answer==n1*n2)
            {
                right++;
                continue;
            }
            if(answer!=n1*n2)
            {
                wrong++;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the purpose of the program is that if the user does not enter a number within 1 second (duration of the Thread.sleep), it will print a message and continue onto the next iteration. However instead if it's answered in time, it will just stop the program. And if it's not answered in time, it seems to get stuck and not move to the next iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: Do you have to use a `Thread` for this? There are other solutions that might be easier to implement.

Comment: Extend `Runnable`, not `Thread`. Don't synchronize the `run` method. Study how to handle `InterruptedException`, which you don't do here. Get rid of the redundant `return` and `continue` statements. Your main thread doesn't wait for the timing thread, so the latter has no effect. The threads share no information, so there's no way the main thread can tell if the time constraint was violated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wait for the answer from another thread. This is how it could be done using a single thread:

```
public class FastMath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int answer;

        System.out.println("How many questions can you solve?");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int total = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());

        int right = 0;
        int wrong = 0;
        int missed = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int n1 = (int) (Math.random() * 12) + 1;
            int n2 = (int) (Math.random() * 12) + 1;
            System.out.print(n1 + " * " + n2 + " = ");

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 3 * 1000
                    && !in.ready()) {
            }

            if (in.ready()) {
                answer = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());

                if (answer == n1 * n2)
                    right++;
                else
                    wrong++;
            } else {
                missed++;
                System.out.println("Time's up!");
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Results:\n\tCorrect answers: %d\n\nWrong answers:%d\n\tMissed answers:%d\n", right, wrong, missed);
    }
}
```